# How to request images and output image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I try to get the image and display on a url. and I use [request](https://github.com/request/request) module.

For example, I want to get the image `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png`, and display on my url `http://example.com/google/logo`.

Or display by `<img src="http://example.com/google/logo" />`.

And I try to use **request** and **express**:

```
app.get("/google/logo", function(req, res) {
  request.get("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", 
        function(err, result, body) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
    res.write(body);
    res.end();
  })
})
```

but the response is not a image. How to get image and output?

Please give me some suggestion about the question. THANKS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try specifying `encoding: null` when making the request so that the response body is a `Buffer` that you can directly write to the response stream:

```
app.get("/google/logo", function(req, res) {
    var requestSettings = {
        url: 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null
    };

    request(requestSettings, function(error, response, body) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.send(body);
    });
});
```

On the other hand if you do not specify `encoding: null`, the `body` parameter will be a String instead of a Buffer.

Comment: Typo on `    request(requestSettings, function(error, response, body) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.send(body);
    };`  no close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

That seems an overkill, you can just ask the browser the get the url directly like this;

```
app.get("/google/logo", function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(302, {location:"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"});
res.end();
})
```

Comment: Getting on the client can not cross domain.