# How to display image taken from external URL on Node.js express route

Tags: node.js, image, express, fetch

I would like display an image which is taken from an external source by using Node.js express. I know that i can use following code if i take image server's directory.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
// Define the static file path
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log('The server running on Port '+port));
```

But, how can i use this if image will be displayed from an external source (from URL)

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to request images and output image in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779503/how-to-request-images-and-output-image-in-node-js)

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's what i am looking for !

Answer (score 0):

```
const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
const imgUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" +icon+ "@2x.png";
response.write("<img src = "+imgUrl+">");
response.send();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: sure @7uc1f3r(https://stackoverflow.com/users/11987538/7uc1f3r)

Here I am fetching icon images from open weather maps API based on the weatherData.weather[0].icon data which I get as a response from Open weather maps